# Are Python's AsyncIO protocols necessary for writing an async HTTP library?

Tags: python, http, asynchronous, stream, protocols

I'm writing a neat little async HTTP library for Python that is a ported (yet slightly more robust) version of the standard library's included HTTP utilities.  I keep coming back to trying to figure out whether it is necessary to even write a Protocol subclass or just implement a StreamReader/StreamWriter.

I have done a good amount of reading through the PEPs and what not.  I'm the kind of person who comes here as an absolute last resort because I hate asking unnecessary questions or preventing those who truly need help from receiving it. Thank you in advance for your exceptional advice and wisdom, friends :)

Comment: I apologize but my previous question was not properly worded. I have corrected it to display my intentions to implement an async IO http library.  Sorry again for any inconvenience this may have caused you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reader/writer pair should be enough.
While we use own implementation in *aiohttp* for some, (partially historic) reasons.